# How to add images to a PDF using jsPDF so that it displays the same on every machine?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, png, jspdf

I have a web application that contains many CanvasJS charts. I use jsPDF to create a PDF containing several of these charts and the charts are added to the PDF as PNG images. The chart sizes are not relative, but a set pixel value. On the machine I've been working on the PDFs are being created perfectly and charts are taking up the whole width of the PDF. The problem I'm having is when creating a PDF on another machine the charts seem to only be taking up 80-90% of the page, leaving a large amount of white space to the right of the graphs. The PDF page is always the same size. In my case I have it set to "letter" size.

So, if the graph's pixels are at a fixed size and the paper is always the same size why are the PDFs created differently?

Comment: The resolution is different and you are thinking that pixels on one machine are the same as pixels on a different machine. A pixel is not a fixed unit of measure (like an inch or a millimeter or a mile).

Comment: @KevinBrown Thank You!